# Weak symmetrization inequalities

Tags: probability, inequality, random-variables, symmetry

Let $X$ and $X'$ be iid random variables, $X^s=X-X'$ be the symmetrization of $X$, $mX$ be the median of $X$, i.e., the number satisfying $\Pr(X\geqslant mX)\geqslant \frac{1}{2}\leqslant \Pr(X\leqslant mX)$. I want to prove the *weak symmetrization inequality*: for any $x$,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\Pr(|X-mX|\geqslant x)\leqslant\Pr(|X^s|\geqslant x).\qquad (1)
$$
I can prove the inequality without absolute value, i.e.,
$$
\frac{1}{2}\Pr(X-mX\geqslant x)\leqslant\Pr(X^s\geqslant x). \qquad (2)
$$
Then, by changing $X$ into $-X$, we have
$$
\frac{1}{2}\Pr(-X+mX\geqslant x)\leqslant\Pr(-X^s\geqslant x)=\Pr(X^s\geqslant x).\qquad (3)
$$
**My question is that**: how can we prove eq. $(1)$ by combining eq.'s $(2)$ and $(3)$?

Answer (score 2):

Note that for any random variable $Z$ and positive $t$ the events
$\{Z \geq t\}$ and $\{Z \leq -t\}$ are disjoint. Then, using what you have already proved:
\begin{align*}
\mathbf{P}(|X - mX| \geq t) &= \mathbf{P}(X - mX \geq t) + \mathbf{P}(X - mX \leq -t) \\
&\leq 2 \left( \mathbf{P}(X^s \geq t) + \mathbf{P}(-X^s \geq t) \right) \\
&= 2 \left( \mathbf{P}(X^s \geq t) + \mathbf{P}(X^s \leq -t) \right) \\
&= 2 \left( \mathbf{P}(|X^s| \geq t) \right)
\end{align*}